# Hide device status bar when hiding SliverAppBar

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-sliver

I have a SliverAppBar setup like this:

```
class PostScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: NestedScrollView(
        headerSliverBuilder: (BuildContext context, bool innerBoxIsScrolled) {
          return <Widget>[
            SliverAppBar(
              floating: true,
              pinned: false,
              snap: true,
              title: Text('News'),
              forceElevated: true,
              actions: [
                IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.share),
                  tooltip: 'Share',
                  onPressed: () {
                    // TODO
                  },
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ];
        },
        body: ListView(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
          children: <Widget>[
            // ...
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Whenever I scroll the page, the app bar appears / reappears as expected, but when the app bar is hidden, the device status bar is displayed on top of my content (at least on iOS, haven't tested with Android yet). I know that I can hide it with the following snippet:

```
SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([SystemUiOverlay.bottom]),
```

but I failed to figure out how to trigger it only when the app bar is hidden, also reenabling the status bar once the app bar reappears. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I have a suggestion, albeit not necessarily a great one. But you could use a ScrollController, find the point at which the app bar is hidden manually (I assume somewhere around kToolbarHeight, which should be the same on all devices), and then use that to trigger the enable or disable system overlay.